# Как избавиться от merge конфликтов?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Часто при коммите в github создается паралелльная ветка, которую потом приходится мёрджить с основной, чтобы совершить пуш. Как аккуратно добавлять файлы в репозиторий, чтобы все проходило успешно?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.
Выполняйте сначала pull, локально решайте все конфликты и только после этого выполняйте push